# Google pubsub late acknowledgement

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I have an app deployed on GKE, separated in different microservices.
One of the microservices, let's call it "worker", receives tasks to execute from pubsub messages.

The tasks can take up to 1 hour to be executed. The regular acknowledgement deadline for Google pubsub messages being pretty short, we renew the deadline every 10s before it ends. Here is the piece of code responsible for that:

```py
def watchdog(businessDoneEvent, subscription, ack_deadline, message, ack_id):
    '''
        Prevents message from being republished as long as computation is 
        running
    '''
    while True:
        # Wait (defaultDeadline - 10) seconds before renewing if defaultDeadline
        # is > 5 seconds; renewed every second otherwise
        sleepTime = ack_deadline - 10 if ack_deadline > 10 else 1
        startTime = time.time()
        while time.time() - startTime < sleepTime:
            LOGGER.info('Sleeping time: {} - ack_deadline: {}'.format(time.time() - startTime, ack_deadline))
            if businessDoneEvent.isSet():
                LOGGER.info('Business done!')
                return
            time.sleep(1)

        subscriber = SubscriberClient()

        LOGGER.info('Modifying ack deadline for message ' + 
                          str(message.data) + ' processing to ' +
                          str(ack_deadline))
        subscriber.modify_ack_deadline(subscription, [ack_id],
                                         ack_deadline)
```

Once the execution is over, we reach this piece of code:

```py
def callbackWrapper(callback,
                    subscription,
                    message,
                    ack_id,
                    endpoint,
                    context,
                    subscriber,
                    postAcknowledgmentCallback=None):
    '''
        Pub/sub message acknowledgment if everything ran correctly
    '''
    try:
        callback(message.data, endpoint, context, **message.attributes)
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.info(message.data)
        LOGGER.error(traceback.format_exc())
        raise e
    else:
        LOGGER.info("Trying to acknowledge...")
        my_retry = Retry(predicate=if_exception_type(ServiceUnavailable), deadline=3600)
        subscriber.acknowledge(subscription, [ack_id], retry=my_retry)
        LOGGER.info(str(ack_id) + ' has been acknowledged')
        if postAcknowledgmentCallback is not None:
            postAcknowledgmentCallback(message.data, 
                                       **message.attributes)
```

Note that we also use this code in most of our microservices and it works just fine.

My problem is, even though I do not get any error from this code and it seems that the acknowledgement request is sent properly, it is actually acknowledged later. For example, according to the GCP console, right now I have 8 unacknowledged messages, but I should only have 3. It also said there are 12 when I should only have 5 for an hour:
[image]

I have a horizontal pod autoscaler using the pubsub metric. When the pods are done, they are not scaled down, or only 1 hour later or more. This creates some useless costs that I would like to avoid.

Does anyone have an idea about why this is happening?

Comment: You are using the wrong design. First, do not delay acknowledging messages so that you can run long jobs. That is the wrong approach. Second, change your design to use a service such as Cloud Tasks that can manage and distribute long running tasks. https://cloud.google.com/tasks

Comment: @JohnHanley Agreed, but unfortunately I found out it wasn't the right designed too late, I would need a short term solution, but I will change the design later.

Comment: Cloud Tasks is easy to implement and is similar to Pub/Sub in some ways which makes switching easy. https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-pub-sub

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll take a look at it

Comment: Consider using the official Python client library for Cloud Pub/Sub to automatically renew your ack deadlines for you https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/index.html

Comment: @JasonGanetsky I am using the official Python client library for Cloud Pub/Sub but I could not find anything related to automatically new the deadline in the documentation, could you tell me more about it?

Comment: @Silveris It should just work automatically. When you receive a message object, until you ack or nack it, the client library will automatically renew the ack deadline in the background. You can test this out by getting rid of your manual renewal.

https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/b58d0d8e404c0a085b89d3407e6640651e81568c/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/message.py#L247

Comment: @JasonGanetsky Oh I didn't know about that! Thanks I'll try it!