# While awaited function not finished run loop to update Cloud Pub/Sub acknolwedgement deadline

Tags: python, async-await, google-cloud-pubsub

All my messages are going to take more than the 600 second limit for acknowledging/processing from Cloud PubSub so while I'm processing the message I need to count up to 590 seconds and request the acknowledgment deadline be extended another 600 seconds(so another subscriber doesn't get a resubmission). My plan was to write  a wrapper that awaits the processing to run and

```
while awaited processing_function not finished:
    update the deadline
```

The basic Code I have for processing:

```
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = "projects/path/to/subscription"

def callback(message):
    print(f'Received message: {message}')
    print(f'data: {message.data}')

    if message.attributes:
        # PROCESS THAT'S GOING TO TAKE A LONG TIME
        # ...

    message.ack()

# subscribe method provides an asynchronous interface for processing its callback
streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
with subscriber:                                           # wrap subscriber in a 'with' block to automatically call close() when done
    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result()                          # going without a timeout will wait & block indefinitely
    except TimeoutError:
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()                          # trigger the shutdown
        streaming_pull_future.result()
```

How could I implement my plan to keep updating the deadline till the callback is finished running? I'm not extremely experienced in asyncio. Would I even be able to have a wrapper function that awaits the callback and runs a while loop as a background process while waiting?

Comment: Ah, apparently the official python client already automatically renews the subscription deadline while the connection is open. they say nothing about that on the docs.
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60212931/13172840), but found this in the comments.

Comment: [official client source code says](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/b58d0d8e404c0a085b89d3407e6640651e81568c/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/message.py#L247)
"The default implementation handles this for you; you should not need to manually deal with setting ack deadlines."

Comment: This is actually in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#dupes): "Client libraries handle deadline extension automatically, but you should note that there are default limits on the maximum extension deadline that can be configured."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[official client source code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/b58d0d8e404c0a085b89d3407e6640651e81568c/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/message.py#L247) says "The default implementation handles this for you; you should not need to manually deal with setting ack deadlines."